# Is there any chance to write "C major" instead of "major C"?

Tags: haskell, dsl

I encountered a small aesthetic issue in my music project and it has been bugging me for some time.

I have a type `data Key = C | D | ...` and I can construct a `Scale` from a `Key` and a `Mode`. The `Mode` distinguishes between e.g. a major and a minor scale.

I can define the `Mode` type as a function from `Key` to `Scale`. In that case the modes will have lowercase names (which is fine) and I can get a Scale like this

```
aScale = major C
```

But musicians don't talk like this. They refer to this scale as the *C major* scale, not the *major C* scale.

**What I want**

Ideally I'd want to write

```
aScale = C major
```

Is this possible at all?

**What I tried**

I can make `Key` a function that constructs a `Scale` from a `Mode`, so I can write

```
aScale = c Major
```

But I cannot confine Keys to constructing Scales. They are needed for other things as well (e.g. constructing *chords*). Also `Key` should be an instance of `Show`.

---

I can put the `Mode` after the `Key` when I use an extra function (or value constructor):

`aScale = scale C major` with `scale :: Key -> Mode -> Scale`

But the extra word *scale* looks noisy and contrary to its name, `scale` isn't really concerned with scales. The intelligent part is in `major`, `scale` is really just `flip ($)`.

---

Using a `newtype Mode = Major | Minor ...` doesn't really change much, except `scale` needs to be more intelligent:

```
aScale = scale C Major
```

Comment: I've myself found myself wanting extremely similar syntax in the past, but TBH it's not worth it. Just go with `major C`.

Comment: Just as a musical quibble: “Key” is a misleading name for that datatype, since e.g. C major and C minor are different keys in standard terminlogy.  “PitchClass” would be a more accurate name for the type.

Comment: @PLL Indeed, I am having trouble finding a good name for C,C#,D ... I know Euterpea uses PitchClass. It is more correct than Key, but not  "musical" at all. Right now I am playing with the idea of calling it Root or Tonic though that suggests only Chords and Scales. 

What the hell do musicians call that thing - a Note without an Octave?

Comment: @MartinDrautzburg: I wouldn’t say pitch class is un-musical — it’s not just programmer-speak by any means, it’s been established in music theory as meaning “a note without an octave” since at least around the mid 20th century.  It’s not very commonly outside technical music-theory contexts, but that’s just because the precise distinction between “a pitch” and “a pitch without an octave” isn’t really needed often in everyday use, and when it is needed, it’s usually clear from context.  But “Root” or “Tonic” sound fine as slightly more familiar terms, if less precise.

Comment: No because it doesn't work vice versa, a programmer going into music

Answer (score 29):

**Solution 1:**

Use this

```
data Mode  = Major | Minor
data Scale = C Mode | D Mode | E Mode | F Mode | G Mode | A Mode | B Mode
```

Now you can write (with capital C and capital M)

```
aScale = C Major
```

**Solution 2a:**

This is also possible

```
data Mode  = Major | Minor
data Key   = C | D | E | F | G | A | B 

data Scale = Scale Key Mode
```

Now you write

```
aScale = Scale C Major
```

**Solution 2b:**

This is also possible

```
data Mode  = Major | Minor
data Key   = C | D | E | F | G | A | B 

type Scale = (Key, Mode)
```

Now you write

```
aScale = (C, Major)
```

Comment: IMO going with solution 2 will serve you well.  Surrender to haskell's syntax and make in it a clean model of your domain. Things can be do pleasant if you do

Answer (score 16):

Here's one whimsical solution that I don't really recommend, but looks very “musical”:

```
infix 8 ♮
(♮) :: Key -> Mode -> Scale
(♮) = (Data.Function.&)
 -- ≡ flip ($)
```

Then you can write

```
> C♮ major :: Scale
```

Of course, where this is really aimed is that you would also have `F♯ minor` and `B♭ major` etc..

Comment: I wonder if there's anything like non-breaking space that's allowed as an operator :)

Comment: @chepner actually yes: `⠀` U+2800 BRAILLE PATTERN BLANK can be used as an infix. Needless to say, this is a horrible idea... All the actual _space_ characters are forbidden as infixes, but unsurprisingly Unicode contains something which can be hacked into the abuse purpose.

Answer (score 11):

If you don't mind an extra operator, you could use `&` from `Data.Function`. Assuming that `major` is a function `Key -> Scale`, you could write `C & major`. That produces a `Scale` value:

```
Prelude Data.Function> :t C & major
C & major :: Scale
```

Answer (score 4):

There are already several good answers, but here's a continuation passing style solution that may be helpful (maybe not for this particular example, but in other contexts where a sort of reverse-application syntax is wanted).

With standard definitions for some problem domain types:

```
data Mode = Major | Minor                 deriving (Show)
data Key = C | D | E | F | G | A | B      deriving (Show)
data Semitone = Flat | Natural | Sharp    deriving (Show)

data Note = Note Key Semitone             deriving (Show)
data Scale = Scale Note Mode              deriving (Show)
data Chord = Chord [Note]                 deriving (Show)
```

you can introduce a continuation-passing type:

```
type Cont a r = (a -> r) -> r
```

and write the primitive note-building types to build `Cont` types like so:

```
a, b, c :: Cont Note r
a = mkNote A
b = mkNote B
c = mkNote C
-- etc.
mkNote a f = f $ Note a Natural

flat, natural, sharp :: Note -> Cont Note r
flat    = mkSemi Flat
natural = mkSemi Natural
sharp   = mkSemi Sharp
mkSemi semi (Note k _) f = f $ Note k semi
```

Then, the scale, note, and chord building functions can resolve the `Cont`s to plain types in either postfix form (i.e., as continuations to be passed to the `Cont`):

```
major, minor :: Note -> Scale
major n = Scale n Major
minor n = Scale n Minor

note :: Note -> Note
note = id
```

or prefix form (i.e., taking `Cont`s as arguments):

```
chord :: [Cont Note [Note]] -> Chord
chord = Chord . foldr step []
  where step f acc = f (:acc)
```

Now, you can write:

```
> c sharp note
Note C Sharp
> c note
Note C Natural
> c major
Scale (Note C Natural) Major
> b flat note
Note B Flat
> c sharp major
Scale (Note C Sharp) Major
> chord [a sharp, c]
Chord [Note A Sharp,Note C Natural]
```

Note that `c` itself doesn't have a `Show` instance, but `c note` does.

With a modification to the `Note` type, you could easily support double accidentals (e.g., `c sharp sharp`, distinct from `d`), etc.

Comment: Nice. I actually did try to solve my problem with `Cont` however, I tried to stick it to the constructors `A | B | C ...` instead of using functions.  I couldn't get this to work and I still don't understand why, given that value constructors are just functions.       

If I can stick a function in front of my Keys, many things become possible. If the function is `flip ($)` then I get your pattern `flip ($) B :: Cont Key r`. My original `aScale = scale C Major` is not much different.

Answer (score 3):

> But I cannot confine Keys to constructing Scales. They are needed for other things as well (e.g. constructing chords). Also Key should be an instance of Show.

You can use typeclasses to cleverly work around that:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data Key = C | D | E | F | G | A | B deriving(Show)

data Mode = Major | Minor

data Scale = Scale Key Mode

class UsesKey t where
  c, d, e, f, g, a, b :: t

instance UsesKey Key where
  c = C
  d = D
  e = E
  f = F
  g = G
  a = A
  b = B

instance UsesKey (Mode -> Scale) where
  c = Scale C
  d = Scale D
  e = Scale E
  f = Scale F
  g = Scale G
  a = Scale A
  b = Scale B

aScale :: Scale
aScale = c Major
```

Now, you can use the lowercase letters for other types too by defining appropriate instances.